# Material-UI text field with dynamic rows

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to have a multiline TextField component that takes all available space depending on a device.

[image: textfield]

I know *fullWidth* but is there a way to have something like *fullHeight* in rows setting, depending on a device that it is displayed on?

Answer (score 5):

A solution is to manupulate Material-UI classes using JSS.

I change the height of the input base and align the text at start vertically.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  input: {
    height: "100%",
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      height: "100%",
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "start"
    }
  }
}));
```

Add the input classes to your input and it's work.

[All the exemple bellow on this codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-dew-m6g3s?file=/src/App.js:117-377)

Answer (score 3):

You basically want your TextField element to take full height and width of the container.

For width you can simply add **fullWidth** prop to your TextField element,

> <TextField **fullwidth**/>

---

For adding required height,

> If you have prop **Multiline={true}** in your TextField element, Material Ui sets numbers of rows dynamically and height is adjusted according to number of row (everytime user hits enter new row is generated), due to this you can not set specific height.

**Now to be able to set height manually, you must add prop** rows={1}*

```
<Textfield multiline rows={1} fullwidth />
```

Now, you should be able to set height with JSS,

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({

  inputMultiline : {
    "& .MuiInputBase-input" : {
        height : '100vh', //here add height of your container
      },
  }

}));
```

Now simply add this to className of your TextField element,

```
<TextField multiline fullWidth row={1} className={classes.inputMultiline} />
```

For any doubt refer to,
material ui TextField API [here](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api) and
material ui styles API [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#api).
(although, no proper information regarding this is available in docs)